# What is wrong in this picture?

Tags: visual

My friend showed me this picture as a puzzle, telling me that something is wrong with it, but I can't figure out what:

[image]

Comment: Well, that huge image scared the crap out of me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's:

> The reflection in the eyes

Since:

> The picture is symmetrical in the vertical axis (this is also unnatural and therefore 'wrong', as @Alpha points out, but might happen with minuscule chance/or could be a model)

We can see that:

> The screen is reflected in the wrong direction in one iris

Comment: I think you're going a step too far here. The problem with the picture is your "since".

Comment: The "It's" part is a great clue to catch

Comment: So since this has been marked as accepted, I'll post what I think the answer is. What's "wrong" with this picture is that one side of the face has been mirrored (which causes the discrepancy with the reflection). There are too many symmetrical parts to the photo for it to just be natural symmetry (freckles, hair strands, also the oddly shaped philtrum).